# The mathematical structure of $\widehat{su(2)}_k$

Tags: mathematical-physics, definition, conformal-field-theory, notation, affine-lie-algebra

Some of my colleagues work on CFT's and quantum groups and I hear them talk a lot about $\widehat{su(2)}_k$ algebras. According to them (and the general physics literature) these are what mathematicians would call [affine Kac-Moody algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kac%E2%80%93Moody_algebra).

However the defining relations of the $\widehat{su(2)}$ level $k$ algebras are rather those of what a mathematician would call the [affine $su(2)$ algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Lie_algebra). To obtain a Kac-Moody algebra one needs to introduce an extra derivation.<sup>[$\ast$]</sup>

Is there a reason for this (apparent) problem with the nomenclature?

<sup>[$\ast$] Also see my other post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322944/</sup>

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: That's what I thought first too, but then I had the idea that the experts here would perhaps know better why the physics community adopted a different terminology. (And because the mathematicians didnt respond to my other question there)